# Slack API error when trying to update the existing message that was posted

Tags: airflow, slack, slack-api

we are running an airflow dag and triggering slack notification as soon as the dag started and updating the same notification if there's any failure/success. It is working fine for few tasks and then it is failing with this error without updating slack notification in slack.

```
slack_sdk.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_blocks', 'response_metadata': {'messages': ['[ERROR] no more than 50 items allowed [json-pointer:/blocks]']}}
```

Do we have any limitations in slack API? if yes, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Slack has limitaion. See https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks. If you can share code it would be possible to understand why